# What is the difference between saying Oh My Allah and Oh Allah

Tags: dua

we use two different prayers and call the Lord Almighty in different ways.

for example

- O Allah forgive my sins
- O My Allah Forgive my sins

What is the difference between above two ways.

Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is the same that is there when u address your mother as

- O mother
- O my mother..

You can Call Allah using any of the names He like..Allah Almighty has Himself given us 99 names..

the difference is in how you feel when u call  upon Him, and How much faith you have in your heart when you call Him..
so are you allowed to call Allah, my allah when making dua?

Comment: exactly. The people of God, those whose existence has drowned in the ocean of God's love. Gain that close relation with God. And hence use the word "Oh **My Allah**" ... Meaning I am no one elses but yours, I have come from you, I have gained from you, and will return to you.  Hence I am your slave and you are my master. And I have no other God but you Allah. Thus; "Oh **My** Allah".

Comment: Also using the word "My" creates that very close relation with Allah. As if you are almost intimately close to him (Just like your mother). Meaning, your own existence cannot be separated from Allah's existence. Allah's existence encompassed everything.